# Bubsenlabs vs xubuntu

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, xubuntu, bunsenlabs

Linux Mint' cinnamon didn't work well on my virtual box. So now I am looking for something else.

I came forward with two top reviews

Xubuntu

Bubsenlabs.

Now as a beginner which is better for me for starting learning linux
( I chose them because I have very bad pc with 32 bit and 3 GB ram and 256 MB graphics card)

Comment: "for starting learning linux"  If that is the target: the desktop does not matter.

Comment: Still I want to learn pentesting so which is preferable